# usecase for etcd inside Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I was just wondering, why it is useful to run etcd cluster [inside Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/incubator/etcd), when Kubernetes itself [depends on etcd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#etcd).

It just does not make sense to me, as if I have HA Kube, I am also forced to have HA etcd outside. Hence to reason to install it again inside...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an external ETCD that manages my k8s HA cluster and im not letting any developer apps near it. I would be too concerned about something going wrong and breaking the k8s cluster. It is also a fixed size at 3 which works well for the cluster size with its requirements.   If the developers need a key/value store for their db and want etcd, this would be a great way to make one in the cluster for the applications.  With it being statefulsets, its scalable.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, you provide a container platform for multiple products? Hence if one product goes wild, you have kubernetes etcd isolated and other products are safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Kubernetes via [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), the underlying Etcd cluster is not exposed in any way.